# Robocopy loops/nests "Application Data" 29 times when copying "Application Data" folder on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, batch-file, robocopy

My goal here is to be able to back up my entire computer by using robocopy. My robocopy script keeps getting stuck here as you can see with the Application Data.

> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Microsoft\Provisioning

Each time it copies, it adds another "Application Data" to the nesting. At first, it started with 1 Application Data, and then 29 Application Data you can see above. It stops at 29 Application Data and doesn't go further.
[image]

Here is my robocopy command:

> robocopy C:\ "F:\Backup Full" /mir /xd "C:\windows" "C:\$Recycle.Bin" "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\AppData\Local\Application Data" "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data" /w:0 /r:0 /A-:SH

I added a few exclusions with "/xd" where it contained "Application Data", but it doesn't seem to be enough so far. Seems like I have to exclude every single place that can have the cursed "Application Data".

I notice that when I try to open the "Application Data" folders on my computer manually, I can't because I get "Location is not available" "C:\Documents and Settings is not accessible." "Access is denied." 
[image]
I went to the properties of the "Documents and Settings" folder and checked the security tab and saw that admins have full control, so I should be able to open it since I'm an admin, but that does not appear to be the case.
[image]

Comment: Read my comment on your original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295716/robocopy-loops-nests-application-data-29-times-when-copying-application-data#comment110177928_62295716

Comment: @Mark Read your comment and did research, but I'm not too sure which one to use:

/XJD :: eXclude Junction points for Directories.
/SL :: copy symbolic links versus the target.

Not sure what junction points are. Are they symbolic links? /SL seems to do the opposite of what I want to do

Comment: I don't use Robocopy. XCopy is better. You didn't try? `/xjd`.

Comment: @Mark  “xcopy is better?” Hardly. Use the `/xj` switch as suggested.

Comment: @Mark & Appleoddity Trying it out right now and will update this comment to see how it goes. So far seems to be working. When it's done, I'll update the comment

Comment: Working fine now with /xjd added to the command